# Jenkins "Device or Resource Busy"

Tags: git, jenkins

When I run the following command while logged in to the VM:

```
git config -- global user.email [myEmailHere]@[mydomain].com
```

this works fine.

However, when a Jenkins job runs the same command via groovy, I get the following error:

```
error: could not write config file /home/jenkins/.gitconfig: Device or resource busy
```

What is causing this?
I looked it up online and still cannot find anything helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your job,try and add, [as in here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433370/7490), a `lsof /home/jenkins/.gitconfig`: as [detailed here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11238/7490), the goal is to check if there is a PID (process ID) which would keep an handle on that file.

That would explain the error message when run from Jenkins.
A Jenkins set to do [multibranch pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48437602/6309) would typically lock that file on a regular basis.